# Prevent closing of Foundation Reveal in the close callback

Tags: modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

Is there a way to prevent the closing of a Foundation Reveal modal in the `close` callback?  I've tried both `return false;` and `e.preventDefault();`, but neither seems to have any effect.

HTML:

```
<div id="my-modal" class="reveal-modal">
  I'm a modal!
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#my-modal').on('close', function( e ) {
    var ok = confirm( 'Are you sure you want to close this?' );
    if ( ! ok ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything in the source code that should provide this feature, no. However, you should be able to use the `close_on_background_click: false` and `close_on_esc:false` options and roll your own close button to take control of the process.